# Getting a fairseq error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fairseq.data.masked_lm_dictionary

Tags: nlp, machine-translation, fairseq

I'm trying to implement MASS on Fairseq for Neural Machine Translation. Following the approach here https://github.com/microsoft/MASS/tree/master/MASS-supNMT, I'm trying to preprocess both the monolingual and bilingual data. I didn't get any errors while processing monolingual data; however, I'm getting the error while doing for bilingual.

**from fairseq.data.masked_lm_dictionary import MaskedLMDictionary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fairseq.data.masked_lm_dictionary'**

I'm using Fairseq version 0.12.2. I'm unable to figure out the reason behind the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [file](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/main/fairseq/data/legacy/masked_lm_dictionary.py), you could use the `MaskedLMDictionary` as a class. To import it you can use the following code:

```
from fairseq.data import Dictionary
```

This doesn't return the error you mentioned.

Comment: In the source code for xmasked_seq2seq, I changed                                     
from fairseq.data.masked_lm_dictionary to from fairseq.data.legacy.masked_lm_dictionary. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for xmasked_seq2seq, I changed from fairseq.data.masked_lm_dictionary to from fairseq.data.legacy.masked_lm_dictionary. This worked for me